# In Django, how to create file field database variable in a query?

Tags: python, django, file, django-views, django-queryset

I know how to create a simple query variable in views.py But I don't know what it represents. As for an instance there is a CharFiled in models.py (model name being Information) named *age*. And to store a single row's data in a variable one could use either `var1 = Information.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]` OR `var2 = Information.objects.order_by('-id')[:1].get()`

From this what I'm understanding is that in var1 stores the queryset list and var2 stores the actual object. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Does it mean the var2 has the *actual value* of the age parameter from the database? If not, then var2 just point to that location?

Moreover, let's say there is a FileFiled called *userfile* in the models.py along with *age* and that takes in the any file user wants to store on the DB. Let's assume the file is uploaded through the form and the whole uploading function is working just fine. Now I want to reduce the *userfile* into half, so for that I need to store the file's data in a variable at first. Can I do `file_data = var2.userfile` or `file_data = var1.userfile`? Again, what will be in file_data? Path to the file in DB or the actual file or something else? If not then how do I store a file's data to a variable so that I can use it? (Django version 3.2)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand Django ORM first :

When you do `Information.objects.earliest("id")` :
you will get the query executed in the database

When you do `var2 = Information.objects.earliest("id")` :
nothing is done in database, it will be be executed in the database when you call `var2`

This is called Lazy : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/optimization/#understand-queryset-evaluation

When you save a file in a `FileField`, you just save the path to acces the document :

`var2.userfile` will give you the `FileField` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile

You have access to this :

```
FieldFile.name
The name of the file including the relative path from the root of the Storage of the associated FileField.

FieldFile.path
A read-only property to access the file’s local filesystem path by calling the path() method of the underlying Storage class.
```

So you need to open the file like that :

```py
with open(var2.userfile.path, "rb") as f:
    file_data = f.read()
```

Comment: Alright, that queryset evaluation perfectly makes sense. Also, now I understand the file field and it worked! Thanks, man!